# jvm memory allocation policy is different for xp and window 7

Tags: java, swing, jvm

I have a heavy java swing app. which run for several hour smoothly in window xp with `jvm param -xmx=512mb.`
but when i ran it on window 7 (32 -bit) it got `heapOutOfMemory exception` within 1 hour . jvm options are same.
My java version is `jdk-1.6.0.`
can anyone please help. What could be the cause for this problem.

Comment: Do you have any difference in your RAM memory?

Comment: do you find the CPU is at 100% before you get the Out of Memory ?

Comment: check virtual memory setting of your `XP` and `Windows`

Comment: both machine have same ram 2 gb

Answer (score 0):

It is the heap that is filling up, so it doesn't have to do with physical memory or swap. The question is, why does the JVM behave differently on the two OS? Regardless, something seems to be interfering with garbage collection, most likely, you are instantiating many objects and holding references to them. In a Swing app, this often has to do with listeners that are not removed. Look through your code for places where you are repeatedly instantiating objects. Ensure all references associated with them are set to null when they are no longer used. Even better, look at ways to instantiate once and then reuse the instance, possibly by turning visibility on and off.